# WCF Calling local Windows Service and not server's

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service. What I am trying to do is to call the Windows Service (WS) which is situated on the client PC and the WS to call a client DLL on the same client computer. 
I have installed the WS on each client PC and on the server. When navigating to the ASP.NET page on the server and I invoke the method, it works fine, but the client PCs instead of calling their DLLs from their local WS, they call the WS that is called on the server - which is not the desired behavior. This environment will be installed on a LAN.

An example method I have is to get the PCs name, which wrongly in return I get the server's name.

This is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="Service.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Service.ICalculator" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My service class:

```
Public Interface ICalculator
    <OperationContract()> _
    Function GetPCname() As String
      Sub OpenPort()
    <OperationContract()> _
End Interface

Public Class CalculatorService
    Implements ICalculator

   <DllImport("C:\App_32bit\test.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Private Shared Function DrvOpen(ByVal cha As String, ByRef ope As T_open, ByRef out As T_open_out) As Short
    End Function

    Public Function GetPCname() As String Implements ICalculator.GetPCname
        Return Environment.MachineName
    End Function

    Public Sub OpenPort() Implements ICalculator.OpenPort
     'some code.
    End Function
End Class
```

Any ideas how to manage to call my LOCAL service instead of the server's Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke method on every network pc with installed and configured windows services, invoking method on your server means that it will be executed only once and only on your server. You need to invoke all your methods on all machines, like:

```
192.168.1.1\MyWindowsService\Method1
192.168.1.2\MyWindowsService\Method1
...
etc.
```

I suggest to create different windows service, which would run only on server and invoke methods on your lan machines.